# Prevent record from being inserted in the table in After Trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a scenario where I have to insert a record in TableA only if the RecordId exists in TableB. I have written an Instead of Trigger on TableA for Insert, in which I am checking if the RecordId exists in TableB, and if it exists then I am allowing the Insert in TableA by explicitly inserting the record in TableA in that trigger

I want to know can I write an After Trigger on TableA, in which I do the same check, and in case if RecordId is not found in TableB then I delete the inserted record from TableA. My question is If I fire delete query on TableA for the same record which I am inserting will it work, and prevent the record from being inserted from the TableA actually.

Comment: Why not implement a Foreign Key?

Comment: Why not test it and see?

Comment: @mxix, I am not allowed to do so by client

Comment: do the trigger with the IF((select COUNT(*) from otherTable where recordID =  inserted.recordID)<0 BEGIN ROLLBACK END, it should rollback the insert on the first table.

Comment: @mxix, rollback or commit in this case is causing error, I had to explicitly fire a delete command in that case on TableA.

Comment: could you try it with a INSTEAD OF trigger and only insert on the TableA IF the count works, you wont insert on tableA and wont have to do the delete.

Comment: @mxix I am doing the same thing, I have already quoted this in my question. I just wanted to know If I can avoid INSTEAD OF trigger and use AFTER trigger instead.

Comment: then ill have to quote @TabAlleman "Why not test it and see?"